# Taxi from Walthamstow Central

Tags: london, taxis

I will travel to London (LGW) this Sunday and I'll take public transport to Walthamstow Central. I would then like to take a taxi to my final destination.

Is it likely to find a cab at aproximately 00:30 or is it advised to call one?

Comment: Are you going place-you're-staying-in to Walthamstow Central to LGW, or place-you're-staying-in to LGW to Walthamstow Central to new-place-to-stay-in? As currently written your question is unclear, and I can interpret it either way.

Comment: @AndyT: the question is not unclear at all.

Comment: Yes, it is. LGW could be your final destination, or you could be saying that you'll fly into LGW, have worked out public transport as far as Walthamstow Central, and then want a taxi for the last stretch to your final destination, wherever that is. It doesn't matter with respect to "can I find a cab at Walthamstow Central at 00:30", but it does matter if you're open to further advice on your journey. And if you're not, then why mention LGW at all?

Answer (score 13):

There are [a number of taxi (black cab) ranks around Walthamstow Central Station](https://tfl.gov.uk/hub/stop/HUBWHC/walthamstow-central/) (scroll to the bottom of the link):

> **Taxi Ranks**
>
> Taxi Rank
>   Selbourne Road (North side of Walthamstow Central Station)
>   Waltham Forest
>
> Taxi Rank
>   Selbourne Road (East side of Walthamstow Central Station)
>   Waltham Forest
>
> Taxi Rank
>   Selbourne Road (Walthamstow Central Station)
>   Waltham Forest

Usually there are a couple black cabs lurking around at all times as it is a large interchange hub composing a tube terminus and a bus station.

However from a price perspective it is almost always better to book a minicab (officially known as Private Hire Vehicles) as they are generally cheaper over the same distance - make sure the minicab company is [TfL licenced](https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/taxis-and-minicabs/book-a-taxi). The "ride-sharing" company that starts with a U operates as a minicab company in London, for example.

N.B.: Minicabs are cabs that can only be booked, but not hailed on the street; although "booking" is often as simple as walking into a minicab office and asking for one (but doing this at busy times means you'll probably be waiting for a while).